# Add dynamic component in the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a project in Angular in which I have created a dialog with several fields for a component. What I want is to take advantage of this dialog for other components, but the amount of data varies.

This is my dialog.component.html:

```
<div class="dialog-container">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="data.name">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Phone" [(ngModel)]="data.phoneNumber">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="data.email">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I want to know if it is possible to create only one mat-form component and display as many as necessary, passing it the number of fields that I want to generate.

This is what I want the dialog.component.html to contain, to achieve the same as above (I don't know if this is possible):

```
<div class="dialog-container">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder={{place}} [(ngModel)]={{data}}>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

From only one `mat-form-field` is it possible to show the same result as the first example?

Comment: yep, use an `*ngFor` to iterate over the number you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom directive :

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForOf } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngFor][ngForRepeat]'
})
export class NgForRepeat<T> extends NgForOf<T> {
  @Input() set ngForRepeat(repeat: number) {
    this.ngForOf = new Array(repeat >= 0 ? repeat : 0);
  }
}
```

And use it as follow in you template :

```
<ng-container *ngForRepeat="3">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder={{place}} [(ngModel)]={{data}}>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```